# Octave index out of bound error. Can't figure out why

Tags: vector, octave

I'm new to Octave and quite confused by this error I'm getting.
My function f works for a (7,1) vector of ones but for any other
(7,1) vector I've tried I get an index out of bound error

To my knowledge the indexing between the working input and the not working one
should be the same, only the values in those indexes change.
So why is this happening, what am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
function asd
  f([1,1,1,1,1,1,1]) #works
  f([2,1,1,1,1,1,1]) #out of bound, 
                     #same for no matter which value I replace with a 2

  x = ones(7,1)
  f(x)               #works
  x(1) = 2
  f(x)               #out of bound
endfunction

function y = f(x) 
  y = ones(7,1);
  y(1) = x(1) − x(2) − x(6);
  y(2) = x(2) − x(3) − x(4);
  y(3) = x(3) + x(4) − x(5);
  y(4) = x(5) + x(6) − x(7);
  y(5) = 200((x(3))^2) − 75((x(4))^2);
  y(6) = 100((x(2))^2) + 75((x(4))^2) + 100((x(5))^2) − 75((x(6))^2);
  y(7) = 100((x(1))^2) + 75((x(6))^2) + 50((x(7))^2) − 10.285;
endfunction
```

here's the error:

error: index (4): out of bound 1

error: called from
asd>f at line 20 column 8
asd at line 3 column 3

Comment: Could you please mark in the code exactly which line is line 20?

Comment: y(7) = 100((x(1))^2) + 75((x(6))^2) + 50((x(7))^2) − 10.285;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to index the number 100, which is a single element, therefore only has index `1`.

Doing  100(1)  is equivalent to saying `a = 100; a(1)`.

Therefore doing `100(2)` results in an index out of bounds error.

What are you trying to do? Presumably you were trying to multiply instead of indexing? In which case you can't just have `100(something)`, you need `100 * (something)` instead.

Comment: I just noticed this error. But I'm confused why `100(2)` is not a syntax error... It seems illogical to allow such a syntax.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to multiply. Thanks! Holy sh*t obviously I'm way too tired to code right now.

Comment: @CrisLuengo well if you think about it, there's no reason why it shouldn't either though. It allows you to do nifty indexing operations on-the-spot without capturing into temporary variables, e.g. `{'Yes', 'No'}{2}` or `100(ones(3))` etc.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I didn't see the use because I've never been able to use that syntax, but especially your first example is quite nice. I like it!